Unable to deploy solana smart contract on mainnet
Deploying the solana smart contract on devnet works well, but if I try to deploy the smart contract on mainnet it doesnt work.
I got this error so many times.
I tried it with so many solana versions.
All versions doesnt work on mainnet.
Blockhash expired. 4 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 3 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 2 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 1 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 0 retries remaining
============================================================================
Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
`solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
============================================================================
daughter strategy stay nerve cave hand congress true laptop river clap metal
============================================================================
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
[BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana program write-buffer'.
Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the
[BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to `solana program close`.
============================================================================
Error: Data writes to account failed: Custom error: Max retries exceeded
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

Anybody can help me to fix it?

Deploying programs on Solana without priority fees is difficult at the moment because there is so much going on on the chain. Also the public end point is ratelimited.
Here is a suggested command:
solana program deploy ./target/deploy/your_program.so --with-compute-unit-price 50000 --max-sign-attempts 1000 --use-rpc

And for the priority fees you can find a good value using one of the RPC Fee apis or this fee tracker and pick the low value:
https://www.quicknode.com/gas-tracker/solana
If you then still have problems use a payed RPC urls, for example triton, helius, quicknode etc.
When you have an RPC with a staked connection you should use the --use-rpc flag. If the connection is not staked try without it.
Also good to know. If a deploy fails you can find and close the buffers:
solana program show --buffers

and then you can close them useing
solana program close bufferID

This will get you your sol for the buffer account back.
Here is a docs page about program deploys:
https://solana.com/de/docs/programs/deploying
